# Xcode5 - Can not add my Apple ID

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode5

I had downloaded new Xcode5 from AppStore, and found Accounts menu in Preferences. (short cut :  **Command + Comma(,)**)

I have 3 Apple IDs assolciated with an Apple Developer Program. It was successful to add 2 of them, but I can't add the last one. Whenever I try, I get below error message:

> Could not parse server's response as a plist

[image]

I have no idea why I can't sign in with the specific Apple ID, the last one.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Wait a few hours and try again. If that fails, contact Apple.

Comment: The one which is not working, have you tried signing it outside the xcode in the browser?

Comment: Yes, it's working well in the browser. If it fails again a few hours later, I'll need to contact to Apple.

Comment: I agree with @AbhiBeckert, I have experienced the same thing with an account which has been already added and used – probably the issue is on Apple's side.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, it was solved.

Now, it works well after removing letter ampersand(&) from last name of the account on iOS Dev website.

If you have same problem as mine, you can simply go to the dev center website and change your profile.